# AWS SQS - SpringBoot - 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, amazon-eks

I'm trying to access the AWS SQS list from a SpringBoot app which is deployed on AWS/eks but I am getting a 403 Forbidden as an error.

Do I have to add something specific to the AWS SQS Access Policy in order to grant access to the client as a producer/consumer?

I am not trying to push into the queue so far, I just want to see the list of the queues.

Thanks in advance

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**AwsSqsController.java**

```
...
public ResponseEntity<ListQueuesResult> readQueueList() {
    AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    ListQueuesResult listOfQueues = sqs.listQueues();
    log.info("List of Queues: {}", listOfQueues);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(listOfQueues);
}
```

**AWS SQS Access Policy**

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "HCDQueuePolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AlwaysEncrypted",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAppOperatorEngineer",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::X:role/role-name"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SetQueueAttributes",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AlwaysSameOrg",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:PrincipalIsAWSService": "false"
        },
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "00000000000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "QueueProducerAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::X:role/role-name"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-X00000"
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      "Sid": "QueueConsumerAccessViaVpcEndpoint",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::X:role/role-name"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-X00000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "QueueConsumerAccessNotViaVpcEndpoint",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::X:role/role-name"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "QueueAdminAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::X:role/role-name"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:PurgeQueue",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow S3 notifications",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:X:queue-name",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "X"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to explicitly allow to read from the queue.

If I'm not wrong, it is with the

```
    "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
    "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
    "sqs:DeleteMessage" Actions
```

You have it in 2 places, so first i would check, if the conditions for those Actions are met.

If you are in control of the policy, I would:

1. make copy of it
2. slowly remove security until you can connect
3. find out why you could not connect originally (obligatory slap yourself on the forehead :)
4. Add removed security back

Comment: What `"sqs:DeleteMessage" Actions` is?

Comment: The Array of Action fields describes what action the owner of the policy is allowed to execute.
The resource = limits on what resource the actions are executable. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html